# Limit Creating Functor

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

This is exercise 5.5.1 of Maclane's book "Categories for the Working Mathematician".

Let $X$ be any category. Prove that the projection $P:X^2 \to X \times X$ sending each arrow $f:x \to y$ to the pair $(x,y)$ creates limits. (Here $X^2$ is the functor category whose domain category has two objects, denoted by $1$ and $2$, and only a morphism between them).

Suppose we are given an (small) indexing category $J$ and a functor $F:J \to X$. I was able to find, for each limiting cone $\tau: (x,y) \to PF$, an element $f: x \to y$ in $X^2$ and a cone $f \to F$. Namely, I took $f:x \to y$ to be the second component of the unique arrow $(x,x) \to (x,y)$ given by the universal property of limit, when considering the cone $(x,y) \to PF$ obtained from $\tau$ by precomposing it with $(id, f_i)$, where in this case $f_i$ is the image of the unique arrow $1 \to 2.$

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Prove that $P$ creates limits. I thought it was clear from the statement. I have edited it accordingly.

Comment: You can do it in much more generality: for any categories $\mathcal{D}$ and $\mathcal{X}$, the projection $[\mathcal{D}, \mathcal{X}] \to [\operatorname{ob} \mathcal{D}, \mathcal{X}]$ creates limits.

Comment: @ZhenLin : by ob (D) I guess you mean the discrete category whose objects  belong to D. Correct?

Comment: @ZhenLin : In order to solve the general statement, we need to extend a functor $f: Ob \mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{X}$, which is the limit of the some diagram $PF$, to a functor $\mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{X}$. 
However I am having trouble in this part, I want to use the universal property of a limit cone in some way, but I was not able to construct a suitable cone from some functor $Ob \mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{X}$ to the diagram $PF$. Could you please give a hint?

Comment: You should first show that limits in $[\operatorname{ob} \mathcal{D}, \mathcal{X}]$ can be computed componentwise.